# Meaning of the phrase "dipole moment of the combination"

Tags: electrostatics, definition, dipole

Here is a question I came across in a book:

> Three point charges $-q$,$-q$ and $2q$ are placed on the vertices of an equilateral triangle of side length $d$ units.What is the **dipole moment of the combination**?

I had learnt that the dipole moment is defined for 2 point charges only with equal magnitudes but opposite character.I am in a bit of a fix regarding what the author means by that phrase in bold.Thank you in advance!

Edit:I just noticed theoretical physics has been merged here;I sincerely apologise if the question is unbearably stupid.

Comment: Also see: [How would we calculate the dipole moment of a charge combination (of 3 or more charges) whose magnitudes are different but net charge is zero?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/399426/238167)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dipole moment is a vector and can be calculated using formula

$$\vec{p} = \sum_i q_i \vec{r}_i.$$

It can be shown easily using the formula above that in case of two charges separated by distance $d$

$$\vec{p} = q \vec{d},$$

where vector $\vec{d}$ goes starts at negative ends at positive charge.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_dipole_moment#Dipole_moment_density_and_polarization_density

Answer (score 2):

> I had learnt that the dipole moment is defined for 2 point charges only with equal magnitudes but opposite character.

Actually, that is not the case. You can calculate a dipole moment for *any* charge distribution.

In fact, the dipole moment is just one of a whole series of [multipole moments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_moment) which can be used to describe a charge distribution.

- The monopole moment $$q = \sum_i q_i$$
- The dipole moment $$\vec{p} = \sum_i q_i \vec{r}_i$$
- The quadrupole moment $$\overset{\leftrightarrow}{Q} = \sum_i q_i(3 \vec{r}_i \otimes \vec{r}_i - r_i^2)$$

and so on. These moments are kind of analogous to the coefficients of a Taylor series expansion.

It turns out that if you take a positive point charge and a negative point charge of equal magnitude and bring them infinitesimally close together, then the resulting charge distribution (called a dipole) has *only* a dipole moment. All the other multipole moments are zero. That's where the dipole moment gets its name. You've been taught that you can calculate a dipole moment for a system of two charges because that is the simplest way to create a charge distribution with a dipole moment. But it is not the only way.